# Java function Date() return values in GMT - 00 time zone, but I'm at GMT -3

Tags: java, datetime

I have to write datetime in a MySQL database:
i need simple as this:

```
this.repes.get(parcelaIdx).setFechaCosecha(new Date());
```

But because the date is three hours ahead!!, so it's  `GMT -00`, and I'm at `GMT -03` (Argentina).

How can I get current and local machine date and time??

**Edit:** to clarify, just a little code:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class AllTimeZones{
public static void main(String args[]){

    String[] AllID= TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
    Date myDate = new Date();

    for(int i=0;i<AllID.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("TimeZone ["+(i+1)+"] ==>"+TimeZone.getTimeZone(AllID[i]));
        System.out.println("myDate sin TimeZone:" + myDate);

        DateFormat dfm = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");

        dfm.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(AllID[i]));
        System.out.println("myDate con TimeZone:" + dfm.format(myDate) );
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all. To clarufy things, here a little code:

Answer (score 2):

Date objects do not support timezones, they are just "specific instant in time".
 Whenever you need date along with timezone information use [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) instead.

**P.S:** I would suggest whenever you write time to a database, always write in GMT/UTC format. So using new Date() will give in that format(GMT+0) already. And later when you retrieve it form DB and show to client convert it appropriately.

Comment: ok, the is that I don't need time zone information, I want the current time stamp, where my write to the database occurs, obviusly local time !!

Comment: @Nicolas400 OK, I always advice whenever you write time to a database write in GMT/UTC format. So using new Date() will give in that format already. And later when you retrieve it form DB and show to client convert it appropriately.

Comment: so let me see if i get it. my localtime is in GMT -3, when I write to the DB, using only Date(), teh value ina Date field are stored in GMT -0, when I read it with a Java client, I'll convert it to GMT-3, but if a query the table with another tool I will see it in GMT -0 ??

Comment: @Nicolas400 perfect. Just one small point. Although the Date() object doesent store timezone info, its toString() method uses your current TimeZone to display the time based on your current GMT-3 format(see Date.toString()). Note that the date object still stores the time without any TZ info, it just temporarily uses ur current TZ in toString() to convert to human-readable string

Comment: hi @suraj-Chandran, well I run a test, and allthough I try to write to the database in GMT-3, it allways stored in GMT-0... but If I want to store in anoter GMT ? should I change from Date to String or Number ?? in the database field type ?

Comment: @Nicolas400 If u use Date to store, it will store in GMT-0 only. The only place where Date uses Timezone is toSring().

Answer (score 1):

Here we go again. A Date doesn't have a time zone. It's an instant in time. It's only when it's displayed in a human-readable format that a timezone is used. Change the way the date is displayed. It's constructed correctly.

Comment: so what I nedd is to pass the date() function by a human-readable function, even if I only want to store in database ?

Comment: No. You need to display it using the appropriate timezone after getting the date out of the database.